# When using mongodb aggragation with $graphLookup followed $limit, will mongodb optimize $graphLookup to only find the first $limit docs?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have some documents with following structures in my mongodb:

```
{
...
id: "id1"
depends: ["id2", "id3"]
...
}
```

Basically, it means this "id1" object depends on "id2" and "id3".

I have a use case where I need to find if given an object id, is there any other objects depend on it? For example, if I give input "id2", the answer should be "yes" because document "id1" depends on "id2"

I'm trying to achieve this goal by using aggregation with [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#examples) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-limit). I don't need to know exactly which documents are depend on the input, so I put $limit to 1 and check if there is any document returns.

The problem is, I may have many documents depends on a single document, thus $graphLookup may return a very long list. I don't really want to waste memory for those information I don't need. So my questions are:

1. Does mongodb optimize my aggregation pipeline automatically and only return after find 1 document during $graphLookup? The document in $limit mentions mongodb will optimize memeory if you use $sort and $limit together, but doesn't mention any other operator.
2. Maybe my approach is totally wrong in the first place and there is better way to solve this problem than using $graphLookup and $limit?

Comment: I think $graphLookup does not have any out-of-the-box optimization for it. For a brief look of your case, you seems that you just need any 1 document that depends on `id2`. Wouldn't a simple `.find({depends: "id2"})` suffice for your case?

Comment: Are you only trying to find direct depends like shown, or should the query also return indirect, like if `id4` depends on `id5`, and `id5` depends on `id2` should the query for "depends on `id2`" return both of these or just `id5`?

Comment: @Joe Only direct depends is enough for me

Comment: Then you don't need graphLookup at all, a simple find like @ray suggested should do what you need, perhaps a `countDocuments` if there is an index on the depends field and you only need to know if it is 0 or not.

Comment: Great Thanks Joe & ray